# How to change Android device's default search engine?

Tags: search

I am trying to play with Android...To change the default search engine (now is Google, or add more selectables) when I press the "search" button on the device.

Is there anyway to do it? I have HTC Hero and HTC Desire, already rooted

Comment: It seems to depend on manufacturer and/or country: [Motorola Permits Chinese Users to Change Android Phones Search Engine](http://www.free-press-release.com/news-motorola-permits-chinese-users-to-change-android-phones-search-engine-1264409418.html).

Comment: A search engine other than Google?  On an Android phone?  That's heresy!

Comment: @DaveRook That question is about changing the search engine in a browser. This one is about changing what happens when you press the *search* hard-key (which used to be common on phones).

Comment: Possibly helpful/similar http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39575/how-do-you-set-the-default-search-engine-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible. It's not locked in to Google, but determined by manufacturer and/or carrier. (For instance, there was a bit of a tempest in a teapot when a new phone was released with Bing as the search engine.)

I do not know if this is something that can be got around by rooting.

Comment: Thank you. Any hacker way to do it? Such as replace a compiled file or something, haha?

Answer (score 0):

Any app can offer to handle the *intent* generated when you press the *search* key, just like how an app can handle the *intent* from the home key in order to replace the default home screen. So all you need to do to change the search behaviour is to install an app with that feature.