# Browser's default search engine

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, samsung-galaxy-s-2, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Android device's default search engine?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4218/how-to-change-android-devices-default-search-engine)

I bought a Samsung Galaxy S II, and when I typed into the default search bar, it sent me and my search to the most obvious seaching engine of the web: Yahoo!... well, almost the most obvious...

Anyway, I went to the browser setting and the only search engine available is Yahoo!. I really want it to be Google, is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is not asking the same as the "How can I change the default browser?" is asking. In this case Raphael is asking about the default search engine not about the default browser.