# How do you set the default search engine in firefox?

Tags: search, firefox-for-android

In firefox if I type a bunch of words instead of a web address and hit go it does a google search.

You can install addons for other search engines and they appear in a list below the address bar and you can click those to perform the search on that engine instead.

Is there a way to make one of these search add-ons the default?

Comment: There are some settings in the `about:config` screen that seem relevant to this (search the config page for "search" and you'll see them), but I've never been able to make them work with anything other than Google.

Comment: There is the ["Second Search" extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/second-search/), which [suggests to be available for Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/android/addon/second-search/reviews/?page=1) as well. Not using Firefox on Android, I cannot tell if it really works here -- but it might be worth a try. I use it on my Linux machine, and it not only lets you set a prefered search engine easily, but also lets you easily switch between installed search engines.

Comment: Thanks guys. Figured it out by looking at the desktop version. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out by looking at the desktop version.

Enter "about:config" into the address bar.
Search for "keyword.url"
Set the value of this setting to the new search provider. For example: "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q="

UPDATE:
This has changed in the newer versions of Firefox (desktop version too).

You now have to install search engine addons.
Then enter "about:addons" in the address bar.
Long press on the search engine add on that you wish to be default and select "Set as Default" from the menu that appears.